# How can I keep pivot_wider() from dropping factor levels in names?

Tags: r, tidyr

I would really like pivot_wider to create a column with NAs if the level of a factor exists but never appears in the data when it's used as a names_from argument. For example, the first line gives me a two column tibble, but I'd really like the three column tibble below.

```
tibble(Person=c("Sarah", "Jackson", "Jackson"), Rank=c(1,1,2), 
       FavoriteAnimal=factor(c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat")))%>%
    group_by(Person)%>%arrange(Rank)%>%slice(1)%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = FavoriteAnimal, values_from=Rank)
```

`tibble(Person=c("Jackson", "Sarah"), Dog=c(1,1), Cat=c(NA,NA))`

How can I get my column of NAs for levels not appearing in my dataset?

Comment: Try using parameter `names_expand = TRUE` which has been made available with [`tidyr 1.2.0`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#pivoting-1-2-0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `names_expand = TRUE` in `pivot_wider` to include all factor levels in the pivot:

```r
tib %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = FavoriteAnimal, values_from = Rank, 
              names_expand = TRUE)

  Person    Cat   Dog
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Jackson    NA     1
2 Sarah      NA     1
```

data

```r
tib <- tibble(Person=c("Sarah", "Jackson", "Jackson"), Rank=c(1,1,2), 
       FavoriteAnimal=factor(c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat")))%>%
  group_by(Person)%>%arrange(Rank)%>%slice(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can first add the missing levels and then do the transformation:

```
tibble(Person = c("Sarah", "Jackson", "Jackson"), 
       Rank = c(1, 1, 2), 
       FavoriteAnimal = factor(c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat"))) %>%
 group_by(Person) %>%
 arrange(Rank) %>% 
 slice(1) %>%
 complete(FavoriteAnimal = FavoriteAnimal) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = FavoriteAnimal, values_from = Rank)

  Person    Cat   Dog
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Jackson    NA     1
2 Sarah      NA     1
```

Comment: Did not know about the complete function, this is great! Just a note--this only works as desired because we're still working on a grouped tibble!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `tidyr::spread` - `spread(key = FavoriteAnimal, value = Rank, drop = FALSE)` gives you what you want.

Unfortunately the `drop` argument seems to have been lost in the transition from `spread` to `pivot_wider`.

Comment: Looks like there's [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/770) for this

Comment: FYI - tidy::spread is superseded by pivot_wider in tidyr version 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `slice(1)` operation is removing Jackson's Cat ranking. If you remove it from your operation, and add the `pivot_wider` parameter `values_fill = NA` you get a 3 column tbl. The only difference between my answer and your goal is that my answer retains Jackson's Cat ranking value.

```
tibble(Person=c("Sarah", "Jackson", "Jackson"), Rank=c(1,1,2), 
       FavoriteAnimal=factor(c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat")))%>%
    group_by(Person)%>%arrange(Rank)%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = FavoriteAnimal, values_from=Rank, values_fill = NA)
```

Based on the help documentation for dplyr::slice, it appears that you are trying to select only the top ranked animal for each person, so this solution doesn't do that. But depending on where you are going with this, there may be other ways such as `dplyr::select` or `dplyr::filter` perhaps combined with `dplyr::across` to accomplish this.